# Capture the WiFi signal from video camera, with Android

Tags: android, video-streaming, wifi, android-wifi, wifimanager

My camera can stream live the video it shoots live, via Wi-Fi;  I want to capture this stream on an Android smartphone, as I need to further process the video.
Camera model is Panasonic HD-V550.  (other models like HD-V750, HD-V720, HD-V520 do exactly the same)

There is this mode called "Baby-monitor mode"; I asked Panasonic about it and they said that video is sent uncompressed, "the way it is shot by the camera" if I understood well.  I assume this means raw video. Anyway the fact that it's uncompressed and not downsampled (unlike in Live Cast mode-streaming to Ustream server) makes it to be exactly what I need.

Panasonic provides an application called "Image App"  (http://panasonic.jp/support/global/cs/soft/image_app) but it's not open source.  This application makes it possible to see the video on the smartphone's screen, but I don't need only that, I want to use the video for further manipulation, encoding, etc so I want to write a new program from scratch.

My question is how can I know what the type of the WiFi video signal is and what Android APIs to use in order to capture this video stream; so I know how to start the development.

Any help or even hints highly appreciated.

Comment: Excepted if you are really lucky and find panasonic specs on the web, i would say this is not possible to do as you don't know how their packets are formatted.

Comment: @Windranger : Did you found any solution? Or any other camera ?

Answer (score 1):

I think [GStreamer](http://docs.gstreamer.com/display/GstSDK/Android+tutorials) may be helpful for you.

Answering on your question

> how can I know what the type of the WiFi video signal is

GStreamer have internal logic for detecting input signal you can just use [playbin2 plugin](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/gstreamer-sdk/data/docs/2012.5/gst-plugins-base-plugins-0.10/gst-plugins-base-plugins-playbin2.html#playbin2)

Answer (score 0):

You can try by decompiling the "image app" and see what's inside it. See http://apkstudio.codeplex.com/
Your goal is to see the url that the app is using for the camera etc. There's some protection there too, I guess....

Comment: Thanks for the link, Owadvl;  yeah that would be a tough approach...  so no other options in sight...?